# How to use lsf.yaml with snakemake?

Tags: snakemake, lsf

I would like to use snakemake with LSF.
I follow [this url](https://github.com/Snakemake-Profiles/snakemake-lsf#non-standard-rule-specific-cluster-resource-settings) .

My Snakefile contain:

```
rule all:
input:
    "foo.txt",
    "file.out"

rule foo:
    input: "foo.txt"
    output: "bar.txt"
    shell:
        "set +o pipefail; grep bar {input} > {output} "

rule bar:
    input: "bar.txt"
    output: "file.out"
    shell:
        "echo blah > {output}"
```

In the same path, I have the file lsf.yaml. The file contain:

```
__default__:
  - "-q medium"
foo:
  - "-q short"
```

It's run okay when I run it with the command :

> snakemake -j 1

It failed when I tried to test it with lsf. I run:

> snakemake -j 1  --cluster "bsub"

I got:

> Building DAG of jobs... Using shell: /usr/bin/bash Provided cluster
>   nodes: 1 Job counts:
>           count   jobs
>           1       all
>           1       bar
>           1       foo
>           3
>   
>   [Thu Jun 18 15:47:21 2020] rule foo:
>       input: foo.txt
>       output: bar.txt
>       jobid: 2
>   
>   Memory reservation is (MB): 1024 Memory Limit is (MB): 1024 training:
>   No such queue. Job not submitted. Error submitting jobscript (exit code 255):
>   
>   Shutting down, this might take some time. Exiting because a job
>   execution failed. Look above for error message Complete log:
>   /home/student6/snakemake_test/.snakemake/log/2020-06-18T154721.snakemake.log

In the log file I have the same message as above plus:

> Error submitting jobscript (exit code 255):

How can I make snakemake run with LSF?
Thanks.

Comment: It appears snakemake-lsf-profile requires specifying [--profile](https://github.com/Snakemake-Profiles/snakemake-lsf#usage), which is missing in your command. However, your error message seems to suggest this profile is somehow identified and used. What is the lsf queue name used here?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is you are using the `--cluster` option instead of `--profile`. So, if you named your profile `bsub`, following the install instructions [here](https://github.com/Snakemake-Profiles/lsf#profile), then this *should* fix the issue for you

```
$ snakemake -j 1 --profile "bsub"
```

Answer (score 0):

> No such queue. Job not submitted. Error submitting jobscript (exit code 255):

perhaps this is the key error message.  Do the configured queues exist in your LSF cluster?

```
__default__:
  - "-q medium"
foo:
  - "-q short"
```

Use `bqueues` to list the available queues.  short is one of the pre-configured queues, but medium isn't.

Comment: both queues defined in lsf